# MATLAB command to call a specific input argument when using varargin

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for a command to do something like this:
say I have a function

```
function [] = myfunction(varargin)
```

then in my code, I would like to to operate on one of the inputs, say input 2, so:

```
if input(2) == 0
```

a command similar to `input` is what I'm looking for, does it exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
if varargin{2} == 0
```

Or, more robustly

```
if (nargin>1) && (varargin{2} == 0)
```